# Why does the session id change on some records?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session, post

this is my config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 86400; //1 day
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400; //1 day
```

I don't know why my session_id changes whenn im dealing with some records.

Here's the error log of the record that the session_id doesn't change (which is correct) (AJAX post):

```
[Thu Mar 19 14:26:14.080447 2015] [:error] [pid 7902] [client 192.168.10.126:58565] f83e35227ac23f60d175dbbb333f9554    <----- session Id (Ajax), referer: http://192.168.10.126/consumer/ignite.php/update_listings_controller?listingId=1129
[Thu Mar 19 14:26:15.516590 2015] [:error] [pid 7902] [client 192.168.10.126:58565] f83e35227ac23f60d175dbbb333f9554    <----- session Id (Ajax), referer: http://192.168.10.126/consumer/ignite.php/update_listings_controller?listingId=1129
```

Here's the error log of the record that the session_id changes (which is NOT correct) (AJAX post):

```
[Thu Mar 19 14:25:42.260545 2015] [:error] [pid 7590] [client 192.168.10.126:58512] 3ff5478a950d3f0d5d71f3c72d1102a0    <----- session Id (Ajax), referer: http://192.168.10.126/consumer/ignite.php/update_listings_controller?listingId=28453
[Thu Mar 19 14:25:47.322896 2015] [:error] [pid 7511] [client 192.168.10.126:58521] 5a7f2424717505a2a68ffe717e56971b    <----- session Id (Ajax), referer: http://192.168.10.126/consumer/ignite.php/update_listings_controller?listingId=28453
```

I'm using the same steps for both. I'm not sure when and why the session_id changes when I'm dealing with some records on back-end. I believe that my config is correct.

Additional info:

```
var opt;
            function showPreviewMode(div,section,editmode){
                showModalElement('pleasewait');
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url:"update_listings_controller/get_listing_content/<?php echo $this->input->get('listingId'); ?>/"+section+"/"+editmode,
                    success:function(data){
                        jQuery(div).html(data);
                        hideModalElement('pleasewait');
                        masking();
                        if(section == 3){
                            opt = new OptionTransfer("serviceArea", "serviceAreaIds");
                            opt.setAutoSort(true);
                            opt.setDelimiter(",");
                            opt.saveNewRightOptions("newRight");
                            var dol = new DynamicOptionList("serviceAreaLeft");
                            opt.init(document.whoDoTheyServe);
                        }else if(section== 4){
                            disAbledFee();
                            disabledMeds();
                            privatePay();
                        }else if(section== 5){
                             checkDay();
                             waitList();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Aside: is the case of `disAbledFee` correct? I wonder if that should be a lower-case `a`, like the call underneath it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is just what I did:

instead of calling `$this->session->userdata('session_id'),`

I'm just calling this:

```
session_id();
```

They don't have same value, `session_id();` is not changing anyway.